# I would like to display the `Indicator` when performing asynchronous communication in Flutter. Is there a convenient way to display it?

Tags: flutter, dart

In this way, `Indicator` is displayed during asynchronous communication.

```dart
showIndicator();
await asyncFunction();
dismissIndicator();
```

```dart
showIndicator();
await asyncFunctionTwo();
dismissIndicator();
```

However, I think sometimes you forget to write `dismissIndicator()`. So, is there a way to eliminate such omissions in the Dart language or Flutter?

Comment: use the Loading state of an AsyncNotifierProvider from riverpod to trigger such things.  And someday soon, I'll finish my "bool isLoading considered harmful" presentation.

Comment: I see. I'll consider it. Thank you for teaching me.